# Policy-based authorization vs authorize with role in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-roles

What is the difference between using policy-based authorization and authorize with role, or there is no difference?

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequiredAdminRole")]
```

and

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Policy-based authorization gives you more flexibility. You can use custom authorization handlers with policies to add more complex logic than just checking if your user has a specific role. For example, you have some roles mappings in your database. You can create a policy that will check if your user is authorized according to that data or that can be any custom logic. You can also create policy only with `.RequireRole("Admin")` which technically will do the same as an attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`
Take a look at how to implement custom authorization handlers in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 9):

For [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0), Roles are exposed to the developer through the IsInRole method on the ClaimsPrincipal class.

In my opinion,there is no difference if you mean the Policy is configured as

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
          options.AddPolicy("RequiredAdminRole",
          policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        }
```

From [RequireRole](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L152):

```
public AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireRole(IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        if (roles == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roles));
        }

        Requirements.Add(new RolesAuthorizationRequirement(roles));
        return this;
    }
```

and [RolesAuthorizationRequirement](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L57)

```
public IEnumerable<string> AllowedRoles { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes a decision if authorization is allowed based on a specific requirement.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The authorization context.</param>
    /// <param name="requirement">The requirement to evaluate.</param>

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User != null)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (requirement.AllowedRoles == null || !requirement.AllowedRoles.Any())
            {
                // Review: What do we want to do here?  No roles requested is auto success?
            }
            else
            {
                found = requirement.AllowedRoles.Any(r => context.User.IsInRole(r));
            }
            if (found)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

You can see that the policy is just to check the result of `context.User.IsInRole("Admin")`.