# ASP.NET Core Web API - abp framework

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, abp

What are the necessary configurations to do role-based authorization over api using abp. I can't find any source on this, the documentation is very poor

I tried the configurations made in a normal web api project related to jwt, but things are a little different in abp.

Comment: Is this document what you want?https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.1/Authorization

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that ABP has a shortage of documents on this issue. You can use it as follows:

`[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`

[ABP uses policy-based](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.1/Authorization) as you know. Again, as you know, [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) underneath the covers, role-based authorization and claims-based authorization use a requirement, a requirement handler, and a preconfigured policy. These building blocks support the expression of authorization evaluations in code. The result is a richer, reusable, testable authorization structure.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465136/9922629